# Proper named temporaries and rvalue-reference/move

Tags: c++, c++11

Prior to C++11, and as a standard programming idiom, temporaries are often assigned to variables to make the code cleaner. For small types a copy is typically made, and for larger types perhaps a reference, such as:

```
int a = int_func();
T const & obj = obj_func();
some_func( a, obj );
```

Now, compare this to the inlined form:

```
some_func( int_func(), obj_func() );
```

Prior to C++11 this had nearly identical semantic meaning. With the introduction of rvalue-reference and move semantics the above are now entirely different. In particular, by forcing `obj` to type `T const &` you have removed the ability to use a move constructor, whereas the inline form the type can be a `T&&` instead.

Given that the first is a common paradigm, is there anything in the standard that would allow an optimizer to use a move constructor in the first case?  That is, could somehow the compiler ignore the binding to a `T const &` and instead treat it as a `T&&`, or, as I suspect, would this violate the rules of the abstract machine?

Second part of the question, to do this correctly in C++11 (without eliminating named temporaries) we need to somehow declare a proper rvalue-reference. We can also use the `auto` keyword. So, what is the *proper* way to do this?  My guess is:

```
auto&& obj = obj_func();
```

Comment: Are you sure using named temporaries is as common as you think?

Comment: What is the signature of `obj_func`?

Comment: I have to second Mark's question... in my experience most people aren't even aware that is an option, let alone try to take advantage of it except in obscure circumstances.

Comment: I've virtually never seen code written that way.

Comment: I'd only ever write code like that if I wanted to extend the lifetime of `obj` beyond the call to `some_func()`.

Comment: I don't just mean a `const&` binding to temporary, I suspect that isn't so common. I just meant the whole idea of assigning to temporaries is quite common. I see it very often, in particular when the temporary could be result of a longer expression itself.

Comment: Actually, I consider `some_func( int_func(), obj_func() )` much more readable than your version with those spurious temporaries. Adding extra variables doesn't always make code more readable. Also, with your version there's lifetime issues to consider (`obj` will keep the temporary alive until the reference dies itself, which might alter observable behavior) and you unnecessarily use names from your identifier namespace (can't have variables `a` and `obj` anymore in the same scope, and probably shouldn't in the same function).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Part 1:**

The compiler is not allowed to implicilty transform `obj` into a non-const rvalue and thus use a move constructor when calling `some_func`.

**Part 2:**

```
auto&& obj = obj_func();
```

This will create a non-const reference to the temporary, but it will not be implicitly moved from when calling `some_func` because `obj` is an **lvalue**.  To transform it to an rvalue you should use `std::move` at the call site:

```
some_func( a, std::move(obj) );
```

Comment: I'm wondering now, would the `auto&&` actually extend the lifetime to be able to call the function?  Also, it seems very unfortunate that one still needs to call `std::move` here.

Comment: The lifetime extension for rvalue refs is identical to that of lvalue refs.  In general, rvalue refs behave just like lvalue refs, except for the obvious binding/overload issues for which rvalue refs were invented for.  On the need to call `std::move`:  It is a safety issue.  Once you have a name for an object, it is very easy to use that object in more than one place.  You don't want to implicitly move from something more than once.  Making moves explicit for named objects helps prevent accidental double-moves.  Indeed, accidental double-moves is precisely why `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt this could be optimized, since it's not clear whether you will use the temporary again or not:

```
Foo x = get_foo(); // using best-possible constructor and (N)RVO anyway
do_something(x);
do_something_else(x);
//...
```

If you're really keen on exploiting move semantics somewhere (but be sure to profile first to see that this really matters), you can make this explicit with `move`:

```
Foo y = get_foo();
do_oneoff_thing(std::move(y));  // now y is no longer valid!
```

I'd say that if something is eligible for moving, then you might as well do the inlining yourself and do without the extra local variable. After all, what good is such a temporary variable if it is only used once? The only scenario that comes to mind is if the *last* use of the local variable can exploit move semantics, so you could add `std::move` to the final appearance. That sounds like a maintenance hazard though, and you'd really need a compelling reason to write that.

Comment: No benefit to the compiler obviously, but it's easier to debug temporaries than inlines.

Comment: @TomKerr that's only because of debugger suckiness. :(

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes  I assure you that sentiment does not console me when I have to debug someone else's code, quite the contrary.  It's not an easy interface problem at all either, I feel their pain.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that the `const &` binding to a temporary to extend the lifetime is so common. As a matter of fact, in C++03, in many cases the copy can be elided by just passing by value and calling the function in what you call the *inlined form*: `some_func( int_func(), obj_func() )`, so the same problem that you are noticing in C++11 would occur in C++03 (in a slightly different way)

As of the const reference binding, in the event that `obj_func()` returns an object of type `T`, the above code is just a cumbersome way of doing `T obj = obj_func();` that offers no advantage other than making people wonder *why* that was needed.

If `obj_func()` returns a type `T1` derived from `T`, that trick enables you to ignore the exact return type, but that can also be achieved by using the `auto` keyword, so in either case, what you have is a local named variable `obj`.

The proper way to pass the `obj` into the function --if you are finished with it, and the function can *move* the value from `obj` to an internal object, would be to actually *move*:

```
some_func( a, std::move(obj) );
```